# Windows azure wasabi

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles, autoscaling, wasabi

When i have created a Windows azure project that used wasabi 'AutoScaling' feature, i have got the below exception, also i have configured the app.config file.:

**Exception**:

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Autoscaler objAutoScaler= EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance(); // Here i got the exception

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still have this problem, but do you have these assemblies referenced in your project ?

*Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient*

*Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime*

Also, if you are using version 1.7 of the Azure SDK, you will need to add this section in your app.config :

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.7.0.0" newVersion="1.7.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.7.0.0" newVersion="1.7.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```